# Explore app files for reverse engineering purposes

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, debugging, reverse-engineering

I want to view some Iphone application source files on Windows. Is it possible? If so what do I need in order to view them on a Windows computer?

Comment: what application files?  you can go to itunes, click on your device, click on apps, then click on an app.  in there you can add and remove files that the specific app you clicked on can view and use.  other than that as far as i know you cannot unless its jailbroken.

Comment: Do you mean debugging / reverse engineering? Or do you mean running them on your windows machine>

Comment: @Till I'm trying to reverse engineere

Comment: @Cobold see my updated answer but be aware that you need to be savvy in reading and analyzing assembler code for such endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For actual reverse engineering, I would suggest you to have a close look at IDA. [IDA supports the ARMv6 and ARMv7 architecture](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/processors.shtml#starter) and is overall the best reversing tool on this planet.

The App files downloaded through iTunes are compressed ZIP files with the extension .IPA. You may use any decompression tool to unpack them. To do so, you may simply rename the extension IPA towards ZIP.

[edited to match OP question comments]

Comment: But how I can view the code of the app? When I open the source code file with notepad it shows only lots of symbols.

Comment: Yes, actual question, how can I view source code of the app? Say I store my Amazon credentials as constants in the source code. Can somebody extract these credentials from the downloaded .ipa file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't view the source code of the apps on your phone.

Comment: I want to view them on my windows machine

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you. I mean that you can't take an app on your phone and view the source code for it on any platform. The apps get compiled down to a binary executable that isn't human readable.

Answer (score 0):

When you download an app in iTunes you can right click in and select "Show in Windows Explorer". Then open the .ipa files with anything that can open .zip

If you want to view the app files on your phone you will need to jailbreak it and then go to /private/var/mobile/Applications and you will have to find the right folder since the app folders are named based on when you installed them and your username (so just go in every folder until you find the one you want).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to look at the source etc?

What I would do is to see if the app exists for Android, and download the APK file for Android instead and check that source code, since there exists alot JavaDecompilers and to decompile java is alot easier than to decomiple machine code (compile iphone apps).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to Jailbreak your phone. Just simply download i-FunBox than plug your phone to your PC (turn iTunes off when it pops) and wait for the program to sync with your phone. than go to the first label (you'll see it in the i-FunBox GUI) and Viola! all the files are right there. Enjoy.